# Unity - soft blur effect for dark void edges

Tags: unity, 3d, shaders, fragment-shader

I'm a former Flash dev working in Unity (or in 3D for that matter) for the first time.

For the game I'm working on, I've designed an interior room like so:

[image]

To represent void/space outside the bounds of the current room, there's just black.
In order to hide the back faces of the exterior facing walls, I've created a snug fitting mesh cutout which sits just below the lip of the wall.
If I moved the camera below the surface, you would clearly see that.

I'm quite new to Unity, and have very little experience with shaders.

Anyway, I figured this would be a good place to try for creating my first shader, but I'll need some help.

I'd like to blur/soften the edges where the wall lip meets the void, like so:

[image]

The only way I could achieve this effect would be by hacky means, like by using a gradient texture (#00000000 -> #FF000000) UVed around the edges of the wall lips, but I suspect there is a more elegant solution by rendering the black surface with a shader.

Currently, even with a basic understanding of fragment shaders and the rendering process, I would have no idea where to start if I tried to write my own. When I read shader script I can only stare in wonder at the sheer etherealness of it. I just don't know how to craft a solution in such basic terms, but I'd love to learn.

I understand the answer is probably as simple as 'use a gaussian blur', but i would appreciate some more input to steer me on the right path, and maybe some examples to help me understand.

Comment: Your gradient method (or equivalently vertex colours) will generally perform better, particularly on mobile platforms. That said, there are some simple shaders we can use without more expensive screenspace blurring — is it always the vertices below the floor level that need the effect? And are they always at the same elevation? If so, we can use worldspace position to tweak the colours.

Comment: The walls are always 3 metres tall, the void edge is at 2.75m height, around the edges. Please expound.

Comment: One way to do this with a shader would be to use the [worldspace colouring trick described in this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136516/39518). Effectively, you tint any pixels below your floor plane with increasingly opaque shades of black.